# Emit Signal Only When QCheckBox is Checked

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am creating a set of QCheckBox dynamically based on some user input like so:

```
QWidget *wid = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
for(int i=0; i<NumberModes; i++)
{
    int k = Amplitudes(i,0);
    int m = Amplitudes(i,1);

    QString ks = QString::number(k);
    QString ms = QString::number(m);
    QString position = QString::number(i);
    QString mode = "A"+ks+ms;

    QCheckBox *check = new QCheckBox(mode);
    connect(check, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), &mapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(check, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), &SelectModes, SLOT(map()));

    mapper.setMapping(check,position);
    SelectModes.setMapping(check,mode);
    layout->addWidget(check);
    updateGeometry();
}


wid->setLayout(layout);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(wid);
```

The QSignalMapper are then connected to another class that performs some calculations:

```
connect(&SelectModes, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SIGNAL(CheckBoxClicked2(QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(CheckBoxClicked2(QString)), &Supress2, SLOT(ListenSelectedModes(QString)));
connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SIGNAL(CheckBoxClicked(QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(CheckBoxClicked(QString)), &Suppress, SLOT(ListenSelectedModes(QString)));
```

What I need is that the classes only receive signals when the QCheckBox are checked; meaning if you check it once, and then un-check it no signal should be emitted, or received. Not sure what the best approach is.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify which event that should emit a signal? When the checckboxes are checked, but not when they are unchecked? One way ought to be to subclass the checkbox. Adding a private slot that emits a user defined signal which is only emited when appropriate.

Comment: Right, a signal should be emitted only IF they are checked. So if I have 3 QcheckBox: C1, C2, and C3; and the user checks C1 and C2, but then unchecks C2, only a signal for C1 should be emitted. Not sure if I am making any sense :)

Comment: Then only way I am aware of (not very familiar to QSignalMapper) would be to go through all checkboxes everytime any of them changes state. Then you could have a public function in subclassed checkbox in which you emit if checked. You could also add a signal to the owning object which could emit a list containing only the checked ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestions given by user2672165 are excellent!

If you want to monitor only the check event but not the uncheck event, one way would be to subclass the QCheckBox widget so that it emits a particular signal only when the checkbox is checked (e.g. `checkBoxChecked`)

Then you connect your signal mapper to the custom signal `checkBoxChecked`, instead of the standard `toggle(bool)` signal.

In this way the slot associated to the signal mapper is invoked only when the checkbox is checked and not when it is unchecked.

Here is a simple example

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QDebug>

class CheckableCheckBox : public QCheckBox {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CheckableCheckBox(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QCheckBox(text, parent)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
            this, SLOT(verifyCheck(bool)));
    }

signals:
    void checkBoxChecked();

public slots:
    void verifyCheck(bool checked) {
        if (checked)
            emit checkBoxChecked();
    }
};

class Test : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        QSignalMapper *mapper = new QSignalMapper();

        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            QString mode = "A" + QString::number(i);
            CheckableCheckBox *check = new CheckableCheckBox(mode);
            connect(check, SIGNAL(checkBoxChecked()),
                mapper, SLOT(map()));

            mapper->setMapping(check, QString::number(i));
            layout->addWidget(check);
            setLayout(layout);
        }
        connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)),
            this, SLOT(CheckBoxClicked(QString)));
    }

public slots:
    void CheckBoxClicked(const QString &mapping) {
        qWarning() << "Checkbox:" << mapping << " is checked";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Test *wid = new Test();
    wid->show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to monitor a change in the check status and then notify to some other portions of the code the status of the checkbox (which is probably what you want) you can do something like this...  You don't even need a QSignalMapper...

I have implemented a test method `testMonitorCheckStatus` to show what I mean.  Note that you need `typedef QList<bool> CheckBoxStatusList;` (at least as far as I know) to use QList as an argument to slots and signals.

*Edit #2:*
The number of checkboxes is set at object creation

Hope this helps

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

typedef QList<bool> CheckBoxStatusList;

class Test : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(int totalCheckboxes, QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalCheckboxes; i++) {
            QString mode = "A" + QString::number(i);
            QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox(mode);
            connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
                this, SLOT(monitorCheckStatus()));
            m_checkBoxList.append(checkBox);
            layout->addWidget(checkBox);
        }
        setLayout(layout);

        connect(this, SIGNAL(checkBoxStatusChanged(CheckBoxStatusList)),
            this, SLOT(testMonitorCheckStatus(CheckBoxStatusList)));
    }

public slots:
    void monitorCheckStatus() {
        CheckBoxStatusList checkBoxStatus;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_checkBoxList.count(); ++i)
            checkBoxStatus.append(m_checkBoxList.at(i)->isChecked());
        emit checkBoxStatusChanged(checkBoxStatus);
    }

    void testMonitorCheckStatus(const CheckBoxStatusList &checkBoxStatus) {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxStatus.count(); ++i)
            qWarning() << "Checkbox:" << i << " is" << (checkBoxStatus.at(i) ? "checked" : "unchecked");
        qWarning(" ");
    }

signals:
    void checkBoxStatusChanged(const CheckBoxStatusList &checkBoxStatus);

private:
    QList<QCheckBox *> m_checkBoxList;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Test *wid = new Test(10);
    wid->show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: This is a great example, thanks! And also, thanks to user2672165.
I have a question though, what happens if the user checks a CheckBox and then unchecks it? The signal is emitted for the first check, so even though it was unchecked it is still passed to the class, at least as far as I can tell after I implement this (awesome) code.

Comment: I realize I have used a wrong name for the function `verifyUncheck`, instead of `verifyCheck` which is more meaningful!  I don't understand completely your question.  But basically the SignalMapper gets only check events.  I don't know if this is what you mean...

Comment: Maybe I didn't provide enough context. Suppose there are 2 QCheckBox created C1 and C2. The user then checks both, but then un-checks C1. Later on in the program, the information that only C1 is checked is needed for some calculation, but SignalMapper has both checked, since C1 was, at some point, checked. I might be missing something though...

Comment: If this is the case, you don't need to monitor only check... I think that you need to monitor check AND uncheck.  You can create a slot that is called when the check status of any checkbox is changed.  There you get the status of all the checkbox and notify it to the other function as you need.  I will try to edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you. I am trying to implement it, suppose that `TOTAL_CHECKBOXES` is set from the main function, instead of private. How would you do it?

Comment: I guess that you can pass the parameter to the constructor of the `Test` class, if you just need to set the number at object creation, and use a QList of QCheckBox (see the edit).  If you need to change the number of checkbox at runtime, then things are a little bit trickier...  But this is also doable =)

Comment: Finally got it working :) Thank you everybody that participated, and especially @user2718008 for providing a great solution!

Answer (score 5):

With C++11 it's doable simply and without `QSignalMapper`. Here's an working example.

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class QCheckBox;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void checkBoxChecked(QCheckBox *checkBox);
};


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox("CheckBox " + QString::number(i + 1));

        connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool checked) {
            if (checked)
                emit checkBoxChecked(checkBox);
        });

        layout->addWidget(checkBox);
    }

    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Comment: Lambda expressions for the win.